# Non deterministic results in Graphviz (dot)

Tags: graphviz, dot

How can I force graphviz to always generate the same layout?

Given a graph:

```
digraph {
    subgraph clusterA {
        subgraph clusterB {
            "B.001"
            "B.002"
            "B.003"
            "B.004"
        }
        subgraph clusterC {
            "C.001"
            "C.002"
            "C.003"
        }
    }
    subgraph clusterD {
        subgraph clusterE {
            "E.001"
        }
        subgraph clusterF {
            "F.001"
            "F.002"
            "F.003"
        }
        subgraph clusterG {
            "G.001"
            "G.002"
        }
    }
    subgraph clusterH {
        "H.001"
    }
    "G.002" -> "F.003"
    "F.001" -> "C.003"
    "G.002" -> "F.002"
    "G.002" -> "D.001"
}
```

When I pass it to `dot` it sometimes generates results with layout like this one:
[image: nice result]

and sometimes like this one:
[image: ugly result]

Obviously the first one looks much better and I would like graphviz to stick to this one.

I tried to pass my graph through `fdp` and `unflatten`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like this has to do with clusters, and you are not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15018569/63733 (comments)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot different render-solutions online and cli. I can't see another output then your second one. But if you prefer the first one, just switch the order of ClusterB and ClusterC.

```
digraph {
rankdir=TB
subgraph clusterA {

    subgraph clusterC {
        "C.001"
        "C.002"
        "C.003"
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        "B.001"
        "B.002"
        "B.003"
        "B.004"
    }

}

subgraph clusterD {
    subgraph clusterE {
        "E.001"
    }
    subgraph clusterF {
        "F.001"
        "F.002"
        "F.003"
    }
    subgraph clusterG {
        "G.001"
        "G.002"
    }
}

subgraph clusterH {
    "H.001"
}


"G.002" -> "F.003"
"F.001" -> "C.003"
"G.002" -> "F.002"
"G.002" -> "D.001"

}
```

[image]